# What "standing on the moon" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What "She was standing on the moon" means in the passage:

“So,” Clee said loudly. I stopped. “I don’t really know a lot about health
and stuff? But I figure you probably know what I should be eating. Like
vitamins or whatever.”
I turned and looked at her from my bedroom door. She was standing on the
moon and if I responded I would be on the moon too, right next to her. With
her and away from everything else. It looks so far away, but you can just
reach your hand out and touch it.

Comment: It is unclear. In the [next paragraph](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4sN-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT120&lpg=PT120&dq=%22She+was+standing+on+the+moon+and+if+I+responded+I+would+be+on+the+moon+too%22&source=bl&ots=u8W25sIF3-&sig=ACfU3U2pJ664772pNpFCW8X9hgkPFlNLnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE-diw2KDlAhXNVhUIHSzQDRcQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22She%20was%20standing%20on%20the%20moon%20and%20if%20I%20responded%20I%20would%20be%20on%20the%20moon%20too%22&f=false) the narrator does respond, but the author does not follow up the 'moon' thing.

Comment: It's not exactly clear, but from reading the few pages surrounding it, I think it means that if the woman responds, she will then basically be right there, involved in the pregnancy with the girl - no staying out of it. The line will be crossed where she's an involved party.